# Plotly mapbox geojson layers works for lines but not symbols

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to draw a map with scattermapbox in plotly with some dynamic zooming behaviors, specifically I want some features of the map to only render when zoomed in sufficiently.  The plotly maobox layers support this behavior, but I can't get the layers to draw correctly regardless of zoom level.

Here's some sample code to set up the data.  Two layers, layersPt is the layer that's supposed to draw symbols, and layerLi is the layer that's supposed to draw lines.

```
latHit = [42.1,42.2,42.3]
longHit = [-83.4,-83.5,-83.6]
coords=[]
for lo, la in zip(list(longHit), list(latHit)):
    coords.append([lo, la]) 

layersLi = go.layout.mapbox.Layer(sourcetype='geojson',
                                  source=dict(type='Feature',geometry=dict(type="LineString",coordinates=coords)),
                                  type='line')

layersPt = go.layout.mapbox.Layer(sourcetype='geojson',
                                  source=dict(type='Feature',geometry=dict(type="MultiPoint",coordinates=coords)),
                                  type='symbol')
```

And here's the code to draw it.  I draw a few points between the layer points, and then add the layers.  [Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdBr2.png)

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
  lat=[42.15,42.25],
  lon=[-83.45,-83.55],
  mode='markers',
))

fig.update_layout(
  hovermode='closest',
  mapbox=dict(
      bearing=0,
      center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
        lat=42.2,
        lon=-83.5
      ),
      style='white-bg',
      pitch=0,
      zoom=10,
      layers=[layersLi , layersPt]
  ),
  height=1000
) 
fig.show()
```

In the plot, you can see the two points from the initial Scattermapbox call, and the line from the layersLi layer.  But it doesn't draw anything for the other layer, layersPt.  I've tried various iterations, changing the geometry type to Point instead of Multipoint, removing the line layer and just drawing the symbol, etc... but I can never get the symbol layer to render.

Am I missing something?  Or is this a bug/quirk in the plotly library?

Thanks in advance

Tried to add geojson layers to plotly mapbox plots.  Line layers worked, but symbol layers don't.